# Chapter 9 Exercise 2 Python for Everybody

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Exercise 2: Write a program that categorizes each mail message by which day of the week the commit was done. To do this look for lines that start with “From”, then look for the third word and keep a running
count of each of the days of the week. At the end of the program print out the contents of your dictionary (order does not matter).

Sample Line:

From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008

Sample Execution:

```
python dow.py
Enter a file name: mbox-short.txt
{'Fri': 20, 'Thu': 6, 'Sat': 1}
```

Here is my code:

```
d = dict()                      
fname = input('Enter a file name: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    exit()

for line in fhand:
    words = line.split()
    if len(words) < 3 or words[0] != 'From':
        continue
    else:
        if words[2] not in dictionary_days:
            d[words[2]] = 1       
        else:
            d[words[2]] += 1      

print(d)
```

This is the output I get `Enter a file name:`

Then I enter mbox-short.txt and receive this output `File cannot be opened: mbox-short.txt`

I don't really know where to start. Here is the mbox-short.txt file: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt , I am doing this on a Jupyter Notebook

Comment: This appears to be a problem with your file path; most of your code is irrelevant.  You need to check that the file is in the local directory, and remove as many other factors as you can.  See [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Trying printing the result of calling `os.listdir('.')`. This will tell you what files can be found just by giving a filename and no path.

Answer (score 0):

Using this file: http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt

1. Download to your computer then upload into Jupyter OR create a new text file and copy and paste it
2. Save it as mbox-short.txt
3. Test whether it works using:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
print(fhand)
```

If it works your output should be:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='mbox-short.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = dict()
file_name = input('Enter a file name: ')
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
    for line in file_handle:
        words = line.rstrip().split()

        # for the edge case
        if len(words) == 0:
            continue

        if words[0] == 'From':
            day = words[2]
            d[day] = d.get(day, 0) + 1
    print(d)
except:
    print('Invalid File')
    exit()
```